# VBScript calls both 32 and 64bit application

Tags: windows, vbscript

Hi I'm trying to run both 32 and 64 bit JAVA from my VBScript in order to read it's version. I've found the way to do it using:

```
c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c java.exe #64bit
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c java.exe #32bit
```

Unfortunately calls from VBScript uses 32bit version of java instead of different architecture. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You should be able to use both of them with same cmd, just use full path to the `java.exe`. 32bit: "%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre7\bin\", 64bit: "%ProgramW6432%\Java\jre7\bin\" and the option to use 32/64 bit data model (`-d32` or `-d64`).

Comment: The main problem is I don't know where exactly is Java installed and want to use one linked in: `c:\Windows\System32\java.exe` and `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\java.exe`. The ones which are taken by default java.

Comment: Once java is installed, it puts the corresponding java.exe into folders System32 (64bit) or SysWOW64 (32bit). You might skip the cmd.exe and use java.exe then. Or put in Full path to it with double quotation mark. e.g. `""C:\Windows\SysWOW64\java.exe -version""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to call both 32 and 64 bit application from special Windows folders: System32 and SysWOW64 I found is to make link to executables placed in those directories.

So running vbscript*32 application needs to create symbolic link:

```
mklink c:\Users\J33nn\java32.exe c:\Windows\SysWOW64\java.exe
mklink c:\Users\J33nn\java64.exe c:\Windows\System32\java.exe
```

This way prevent Windows from "playing" with provided directories.